# UnicodeDecodeError Class Based Views, urls

Tags: python, django

I have this in a app url,  I cannot figure out what is wrong. and the "encoding Error"  I am learning from 2 scoops of django.

The problem is this It is this because when I comment out it's use everything works fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ofertoj/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = patterns("",
url(
regex=r"ˆ(?P<pk>\d+)/$",
view=OfertoDetailView.as_view(),
name="oferto_detail"
),

url(
regex=r"ˆ(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$",
view=OfertoResultsView.as_view(),
name="oferto_results"
),

url(
regex=r"ˆ(?P<pk>\d+)/listview/$",
view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
name="oferto_listview"
),

url(
regex=r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/createview/$",
view=OfertoCreateView.as_view(),
name="oferto_createview"
),


url(
regex=r"ˆ(?P<pk>\d+)/updateview/$",
view=OfertoUpdateView.as_view(),
name="oferto_updateview"
),
)
```

This is my Stacktrace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'zinnia',
 'tagging',
 'mptt',
 'south',
 'registration',
 'blogs',
 'turtle',
 'ofertoj',
 'petoj')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/talisman/projects/tempilo/templates/skeleton.html, error at line 20
   ascii
   10 :     <meta name="robots" content="follow, all" />


   11 :     <meta name="language" content="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}" />


   12 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />


   13 :     <meta name="description" content="{% block meta-description %}Browse through a few featured Isla Vista Restaurants and we are here to take your order. 


   14 : Call night or day (805)689-6969 or order online{% endblock %}" />


   15 :     <meta name="keywords" content="{% block meta-keywords %}delivery,food,take-out {{ entry_tags|join:", "}}{% endblock %}" />


   16 :     <meta name="author" content="Brian Scott Carpenter" />


   17 :     {% block meta %}{% endblock %}


   18 :     <link rel="pingback" href="/xmlrpc/" />


   19 :     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/favicon.ico" />


   20 :     <link rel="home" href=" {% url 'home' %} " />


   21 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/screen.css" />


   22 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/print.css" />


   23 :     


   24 :     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jolly+Lodger' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  


   25 :      


   26 :     <!--[if lt IE 8]>


   27 :         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/ie.css" />


   28 :     <![endif]-->


   29 :     {% block link %}{% endblock %}


   30 :     {% block script %}{% endblock %}


    Traceback:
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/talisman/projects/tempilo/tempilo/views.py" in home
      19.         return render_to_response(('index.html'),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
      29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
      177.         return t.render(context_instance)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
      140.             return self._render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
      134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
      830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      74.             return node.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
      134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
      830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      74.             return node.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
      134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
      830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      74.             return node.render(context)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      413.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
      496.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
      382.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
      297.             self._populate()
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
      274.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
      297.             self._populate()
    File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
      265.             if p_pattern.startswith('^'):

    Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /
    Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It might be unrelated but `'bytestring with non-ascii ʘ‿ʘ'.startswith(u'unicode')` also raises `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: do you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of `urlresolvers.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have unicode code points in your template.  By looking at the hex you can see the raw bytes:

```
280a 7265 6765 783d 7222 cb86 283f 503c  (.regex=r"..(?P<
```

The part right after the r" is a ^ which appears to have been entered in unicode.  It shows as .. and the bytes are 0xcb 0x86. So your regex has unicode but probably should only be ascii, so you should change this:

```
regex=r"ˆ(?P<pk>\d+)/$",
```

into this:

```
regex=r"^(?P<pk>/d+)/$",
```

If you change all of those it probably fixes it.